# How can i pass variables to Azure Marketplace VM offer

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-marketplace

I am publishing an app to the Azure Marketplace. My offer is a VM. My use case is that i need the customer to enter some values that will be used to call a script in the VM. How can i pass custom variables to the VM during launch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/cloud-partner-portal/virtual-machine/cpp-create-offer) you can only customize them with SKU's, so this means any post deployment configurations are to be done by the customer.

What you see to need is an [Azure Application Offer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/cloud-partner-portal/azure-applications/cpp-azure-app-offer). That one would contain a way to customize it.